# Does an SVG 'bend' transform exist

Tags: svg

I'd like to apply a "curve" to a bunch of svg elements in one go, but don't think it's possible to do so. Just wondering if anyone knows a way to do so, or if 3rd party packages exist that allow for circular transforms.

Comment: SVG only supports affine transforms.

Answer (score 1):

to some extend you can use the feDisplacementMap filter to "bend" your primitives. But its use is very limited ;-)

```html
<svg shape-rendering="optimizeSpeed" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>


    <filter id="test" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-0.5" y="-0.5" width="2" height="2">
      <feImage xlink:href="#MyImage1" x="0" y="0" />
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="8" result="out" />
      <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="out" scale="20" xChannelSelector="G" yChannelSelector="G">
      </feDisplacementMap>
    </filter>

    <linearGradient id="grad" x1="50%" y1="50%" x2="100%" y2="25%" spreadMethod="reflect">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#000000" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#00ff00" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000000" />

      <animate attributeName="x1" from="0%" to="125%" begin="0s" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      <animate attributeName="x2" from="50%" to="175%" begin="0s" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </linearGradient>
    <g id="MyImage1">
      <rect x="0" y="0" fill="url(#grad)" width="200" height="200" />
    </g>
  </defs>






  <g filter="url(#test)">
    <rect x="30" y="10" width="150" height="26.666" />
    <rect x="30" y="36.666" width="150" height="26.666" fill="red" />
    <rect x="30" y="63.3333" width="150" height="26.666" fill="yellow" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

I've updated the snippet with an additional feGaussionBlur to make the bending more smooth.